# WinRT: List box does not select previous item on Up key

Tags: windows-runtime, listboxitems

When a vertical List Box item is selected, pressing Down key selects next item, but pressing Up key has no effect! Can I get List Box selecting previous item on Up key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for selecting previous item listbox needs to have focus. After focus is set on listbox it will select previous items as well.